# How to deploy Rails in production mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I put a Rails 3.0 in production mode?

Do I simply just put the following code in config/environment:

```
RAILS_ENV = 'production'
```

Is there anything else I need to change?

Thank you.

Answer (score 72):

It depends on how you're running your app. If you're just using the `rails server` command, you can do:

```
rails server -e production
```

You can also just use `RAILS_ENV` as you mentioned (but do this in a single line):

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails server
```

If you're more specific about your exact production setup (i.e. are you using Passenger, or Mongrel, or Unicorn, or something else?), we could give you a more specific answer for your situation.

While Passenger defaults to run your app in production mode unless you tell it otherwise, you can make double sure. For Passenger behind Apache, you would add this to your Apache configuration:

```
RailsEnv production
```

For Passenger behind Nginx, you would add this to your Nginx configuration:

```
rails_env production;
```

Comment: I'm going to be using passenger on the webserver.

Comment: See updated answer. Note, however, that passenger automatically uses production mode by default.

Comment: Okay, I don't think this works: RAILS_ENV=production in my environment file, because when I run rake db:migrate or rails server I get the following error: undefined local variable or method 'production'

Comment: So how do I set up a production database locally?

Comment: You don't put the `RAILS_ENV` line in your environment file. You put it on the command line with your command. So to run rake: `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate`.

Comment: Alright that worked. Idk for some reason my styles aren't showing up now.

Comment: for nginx add that line in the server block?

Answer (score 12):

This is the answer:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
```

Comment: This of course just does the database migration required, it doesn't run the server in production.

Comment: This does not run the server in production.